# Who is running my web site?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-10

I have a new Windows 10 Professional installation.

Before I installed any component of IIS, http://localhost responded with a 404 for every request.

After I installed just the basic ASP component of IIS, every request to the local machine still came back with a 404. Requets are not going to %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\wwwwroot even though that is the configuration seen in IIS Manager.

Who or what is the web server on my machine?

[image]

Comment: IIS installs a simple static web page to help you identify the server is up. Can you post a screenshot of your IIS configuration?

Comment: Installation of IIS created a `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot` with two files: iisstart.htm and iisstart.png.  However, `http://localhost/iisstart.png` still give a 404 with no other headers, ie I can't tell what type of web server is generating it.

Comment: run `inetmgr` and try to expand the tree on the left as much level as possible, then post the screenshot of that window

Comment: 1. localhost does not always resolve to your local machine. 2. This default site is stopped as shown in IIS Manager, so it won't be able to serve anything. 3. Usually before testing you should install all IIS features, in case it is simply caused by a missing feature (unless you do want to test that case out).